@Slf4j SimpleLogger change log level from code
I am using @Slf4j annotation with SimpleLogger. I have properties defined in simplelogger.properties as below:
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=INFO
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS Z
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showShortLogName=false

I want to change defaultLogLevel based on flag, like:
if(debugging) {
            System.setProperty("org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel", "DEBUG");
            log.debug("changed level to debug from info");
}

but its not working. Whats the right way to change log level for SimpleLogger while using @Slf4j annotation on class?

LogLevel for SimpleLogger can't be changed during runtime. It is set in stone, when the logger is created in org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger.SimpleLogger(String)

what could be alternative to do so?

Use Logback as logging backend. Cast Logger to Logback Logger implementation and use setLevel.

using logback logger solved the issue.
